# How to have Column, Rows array (not vice versa)

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Making game of life I need to a have a grid that is 30x20 (X * Y). The problem is (I had another question regarding to that) that the c# arrays are rows, columns. So when I use `CursorPosition()` to drawing I need to swap it because it wants column at first.
Is there any way how I can reverse it so I can use like this?

```
int [,] Array = new int[30,20];
Console.SetCursorPosition(29,19) // now its vice versa, I would need to use 19,29.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is purely conceptual (c# arrays are neither row/col or col/row that is up to the developer) and comes down to iterating your array in either a depth-first or breadth-first manner e.g.

```
//Breadth-first
for(int x = 0; x < col.Length; x++)
{    
     for(int y = 0; y < row.Length; y++)
     {             
     }    
}

//Depth-first
for(int y = 0; y < row.Length; y++)
{    
     for(int x = 0; x < col.Length; x++)
     {    
     }    
}
```

Comment: Look at MSDN - it is really rows, column

Comment: "conceptual" being the operative word here... do they define 5,6,7D arrays also in MSDN? Thinking about a 2D array as row/col is just making life hard for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

At first I was inclined to answer no as the parameters to  `Console.SetCursorPosition` is *Positional parameters*. But when I remember that C# have *Named parameters* too so something like this works.

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
Console.SetCursorPosition(top: a, left: b);
```

This is the closest you can get, if you want  to know why, search for the terms above

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a data structure to store date in relation with an x,y coordinate.

You do not have to use a multi-dimensional array for this. You could very easily create a class that hides the specific implementation from the other classes.

In fact this will make your design more robust.

You can store the data in a database, bitarray, single dimension array, etc.

Comment: Hiding implementation details is rarely overkill. If the methods are small, they will be inlined (no perf overhead), but it will make your consuming classes cleaner.